# caret for hierarchical classification

Tags: r, classification, caret

I am wondering if there are algorithms in the awesome `caret` package that deal with hierarchical classification tasks? That is, assume each item can be of class A or B and if it is A, it is either A1 or A2. I want to predict class membership of A1, A2 or B.

Obviously we can use any multi-class classification algorithm but there might be a way to incorporate the hierarchical class structure, too.

Comment: maybe you should have multi-class or multi-label modeling? just put A as a separate A1 and A2

Comment: This method would be unaware of the fact that A1 and A2 are much more related to each other than to B.